# mysql dies everytime I try to create a new table

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create new tables every time I post to this method, but for some reason I can not figure out why it dies.

```
<?php

 $host = "127.0.0.1";
 $username = 'cotten3128';
 $pwd = 'pwd';
 $database = "student_cotten3128";
 $pin = $_REQUEST['pinSent'];
 $words = $_REQUEST['resultSent'];
 $tableName = $pin;
 $db = new mysqli($host, $username, $pwd, $database);
 if ($sql = $db->prepare("CREATE TABLE $pin (id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT);")) {
 $sql->execute();
 $sql->close();
 }else{
 echo $mysql->error;
 die('Could not create table');
}
 for($i=0;$i<count($words);$i++){
  if($sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$pin.$words[$i].";")) {
 $sql->execute();
 $sql->close();
 }else{
  echo $mysql->error;
  die("Could not add data to table");
 }
}


mysqli_close();
?>
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered getting the *actual* error? You're also using `mysql_close`, which will not work with `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: What is the message you're getting? `ERROR CREATING TABLE` or `ERROR PUTTING IN WORDS`?

Comment: I don't know what's there in `$pin.$words[i]` but your CREATE statement is wrong, you didn't provide a datatype and range for your attribute `id`, and your table name `$pin` should not be wrapped in quotes. So, your prepare statement should be like this: `if ($sql = $db->prepare("CREATE TABLE $pin (id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT);")) { ... }`

Comment: by "mysql dies", do you mean the mysql server process crashes, or do you mean your php script doesn't work?

Comment: also, replace your `die()` calls with `echo $sql->error;` to find the actual problem.

Comment: Here is the error message that is output, sorry for the lack of information. I also updated the code above to some of the changes that were suggested.
`<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: mysql in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\students\cotten3128\Files\login.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\students\cotten3128\Files\login.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
Could not create table`   As far as I can tell the only error message is due to the `echo $mysql->error;`

Comment: That makes sense, because`$mysql` is not defined (as the message informs). You probably need `$sql` or `$db` instead.

Comment: `Query Failed, Heres why:SQL: 110769/nErrno1064/nErrorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '110769 (id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT)' at line 1/n`

Answer (score 0):

The intention of my post is to help you finding the issue by yourself. As you did not added much information I assume my post is helpful for you.

Based on the code you have shared I guess you mean one of your called `die()` functions is executed.

**Wrong function call**

As Jay Blancherd mentioned `mysql_close` is the wrong function. You rather have to use `mysqli_close` as you created a `mysqli` instance.

Beside of that `mysql_*` is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

**Debugging Steps**

Not only for this case but in general you should ask yourself:

- Is there an error message available? (Frontend output, error log file, ...)

YES:

- What's the message about?
- Is it an error you can search for? E.g. via a search engine or the corresponding documentation?
- Look up in the bug tracker (if available), by the software developer of the software you are using, and if it has not been reported yet report the issue.

NO: (if none error message available OR you cannot search for it as it is a custom error message)

- Search in the files of the software you are using for the error message and start a core-debugging.

STILL NO SOLUTION?:

- Ask on stackoverflow.com e.g. and tell your issue and the steps you have performed to find and fix the bug. Post only as much code as necessary plus use a proper format.

**Debugging in your case:**

In order to narrow down the scope. Which of the `die()` is executed? Depending on that echo the query to execute just before it actually is executed. Then copy the SQL query to an SQL editor and look at it syntax. After that you probably know the problem already.